# Display text with WebGL

Tags: javascript, text, textures, webgl

I want to display text with WebGL, and I know that there is not a built in way to do this.  However, I know it can be done, with textures.  I am new to OpenGL, so I don't really have much experience with shaders, so if someone could add how to set up the shaders for this.  I would like to draw the entire string on the same object, instead of a bunch of seperate letters, and the strings are NOT preset, they will not always be the same.  How can I get the text to appear?  Also, how do I know how to space each letter?

I read post #7 at [`this page`](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6845-Text-in-WebGL), and that sounds like it's what I want to do, but I don't understand exactly what It all means.  (It's mostly the shader stuff I don't understand).

By the way, I am using `sylvester.js`

Comment: zfedoron's answer is the most common way but another question is do you need text in WebGL? You're in the browser. It can already display text. Just asking. I assume you want the text merged into the 3D scene and drawn at strange angles or in perspective but if you just need a HUD or text on top like a score then of course it's far easier to just use HTML for that.

Comment: For debug purposes, I would recommend what gman said. However, there are plenty of reasons to use a bitmap font, ranging from art style to using shaders on the text. You won't be able to do `splinter cell conviction projected text` with HTML alone. You might get close to the same effect, but you won't be able to have the glyphs get masked by the scene (depth buffer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to render text but one of the simplest is called bitmap font rendering.

All you need to get started is a sprite sheet with all of the letters you might want to render. Then you simply render a quad with the texture coordinates set to the location of the character you want to draw. To render a full sentence, just draw a bunch of quads, each representing a single letter.

Your sprite sheet will look something like the following texture.

[image: glyph atlas]

Once you have that, you'll need the texture coordinates, essentially (x, y) coordinates in the range 0 to 1, for each character in the sprite texture. Use these when generating quad meshes. You'll end up drawing something like this to the screen:

[image: quads]

Now that you have text on the screen, you can get fancy and take into account the glyph kerning between the letters. This allows you to render more natural text.

[image: kerning]

---

Unfortunately, I can't find a tutorial to point you to. And its not really something that I can whip together for you here. There are many pieces to the puzzle and its no small task (matrix math, camera's, orthographic projection, texture coords, textures, sprites, generating meshes, etc...).

If you'd like you can look through one of my projects where I have done this with WebGL. I even generate the initial sprite sheet using javascript + 2d canvas.

*Sprite Sheet generated here*:

- https://github.com/zfedoran/prefab.js/blob/master/app/graphics/spriteFont.js

*Quad Mesh generated in this file*:

- https://github.com/zfedoran/prefab.js/blob/master/app/controllers/labelController.js

*Wrapper around WebGL*:

- https://github.com/zfedoran/prefab.js/blob/master/app/graphics/device.js

---

#### Or You Could

Watch Notch (the guy who made Minecraft) do this, in only about 30 minutes, in Java (fast forward to 2:21 hours in):

- http://www.twitch.tv/notch/b/487451713
- http://www.twitch.tv/notch/b/487621698

Good luck, and have fun :)

Comment: both links dead

Comment: That is super unfortunate, his videos were interesting. However, you can find lots of others by searching for `notch ludum dare` in youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Three.js has actual text glyph support.  In addition, dimensionthree.net uses textures on shapes.  if you need source let me know.

Comment: link-only answer that should be an (interesting) comment.

Answer (score 0):

There also is my http://taccGL.org library that can draw HTML text on a 2D canvas and then use  it as textures on 3D objects drawn on a 3D/WebGL canvas.

Comment: link-only answer that should be an (interesting) comment.